# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType', How to solve this issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, computer-science

For this Code,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

data_path = 'dataset/'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(data_path) if isfile(join(data_path,f))]

Training_Data, Labels = [], []

for i, files in enumerate(onlyfiles):
    image_path = data_path + onlyfiles[i]
    images = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    Training_Data.append(np.asarray(images, dtype=np.uint8))
    Labels.append(i)

Labels = np.asarray(Labels, dtype=np.int32)

model = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

model.train(np.asarray(Training_Data), np.asarray(Labels))

print("Model Training Completed!!!!!")
```

I am getting this error

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 "/Users/mac/Google Drive/Read&Write2Database/knowledgeShelfPart-2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Google Drive/Read&Write2Database/knowledgeShelfPart-2.py", line 14, in <module>
    Training_Data.append(np.asarray(images, dtype=np.uint8))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 492, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Check if image path is proper. Error ocuured because `images` is `None`

Comment: it was working fine and suddenly stopped working and started to show this error

Comment: `imread` will return `None` if it cannot read the image for some reason. You should always check the output of `imread` before attempting to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert an entire list to an integer. In order to get around this, you first must convert your list to a string, then convert that string to an integer. Since there are multiple elements in your list, python doesn’t know which element in the list that you want to pass or convert.

Comment: Thank you, but the code was working fine and suddenly it started to show this error

Comment: You never changed any of your input? It just stopped working?

Comment: I made some changes but after the issue, I retrieved everything. There must be something that I am not understanding. That's why I asked for help

Comment: thank you Aaron, the issue was because of the input and it was solved

Comment: @AdnanMuhammad: Please don’t accept an answer that didn’t help you. This answer doesn’t answer the question, accepting it will cause confusion for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot leave a comment. Without a copy of the data it is not possible to know the root of the problem. However, I would check that *images* is not None. It seems that the problem is related to *imread* not returning what you desire, which could mean that you are not generating the filepaths you think you are.

Comment: thank you Sir, the issue was solved and it was being caused because of images is not None

Comment: oops turns out that I can leave a comment after all... glad to see it worked out.